# batchfile : copy active selection

Tags: batch-file

Mean: I want to add a batch file to the right click property.

Action that this file needs to do is to go to a folder and look up the highlighted/selected text that I've selected when clicking on the batch file.

My question is how to get this highlighted text selected into a variable in the batch file?

Later on I can use this variable in the code to navigate to the folder and select the correct file.
I'll use following code then:

```
@echo off
start wgnplot.exe "c:\path to file to open\VARIABLE.pdf"
```

Comment: Go to your Start menu.  In the search box at the bottom, enter `shell:sendto`.  Put a shortcut to your batch script there.  Voila!  Context menu... Send To... Your batch script.  Within your script, use "%~1" through "%~9" to refer to the files for which the context menu was activated; or use `for %%I in (%*)` to loop through each argument one at a time.  I also suggest getting rid of `start` and simply doing `wgnplot.exe "%%~I"` to keep the processing synchronous.  Otherwise, if you select ten files to send to your batch script, you'll have ten concurrent wgnplot threads battling for power.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Indeed the shell command let's me put things in the right click menu.